# Error getting salesOrder in Netsuite while getting a record

Tags: node.js, oracle, netsuite, suitescript

Unable to get single NetSuite salesOrder, Generating below error

```
Getting Sales Order record
Error
[
  {
    '$attributes': { type: 'ERROR' },
    code: 'INVALID_TRANS_TYP',
    message: 'Transaction type specified is incorrect.'
  }
]
{
  "readResponse": {
    "status": {
      "$attributes": {
        "isSuccess": "false"
      },
      "statusDetail": [
        {
          "$attributes": {
            "type": "ERROR"
          },
          "code": "INVALID_TRANS_TYP",
          "message": "Transaction type specified is incorrect."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
Last Request:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tns="urn:platform_2014_2.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2014_2sales.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2014_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:actSched="urn:scheduling_2014_2.activities.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:setupCustom="urn:customization_2014_2.setup.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranBank="urn:bank_2014_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranCust="urn:customers_2014_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranInvt="urn:inventory_2014_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listSupport="urn:support_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranGeneral="urn:general_2014_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listMkt="urn:marketing_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listWebsite="urn:website_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:fileCabinet="urn:filecabinet_2014_2.documents.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listEmp="urn:employees_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"><soap:Header><platformMsgs:passport><platformCore:email>darshan.sanandiya@techholding.co</platformCore:email><platformCore:password>techh@123#</platformCore:password><platformCore:account>5022995_SB1</platformCore:account><platformCore:role internalId="3"></platformCore:role></platformMsgs:passport></soap:Header><soap:Body><platformMsgs:get xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformMsgs:baseRef type="salesOrder" xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef" internalId="106095" externalId="106095"></platformMsgs:baseRef></platformMsgs:get></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

All I want to fetch single order with internalId, But in return, it throws INVALID transction type error;
I am using npm soap; and netsuite sdk with nodejs

```
'use strict';

var denodeify = require('denodeify');
var NetSuite = require('../');

var credentials = require('../example/credentials.json');
var config = new NetSuite.Configuration(credentials);
var service = new NetSuite.Service(config);

console.log('Creating NetSuite connection');
console.log(service,"Service<<<")
service
  .init()
  .then(function( /*client*/ ) {
    console.log('WSDL processed. Service description:');
    console.log(service.config.client.describe());

    var recordRef = new NetSuite.Records.RecordRef();
    recordRef.internalId = "106095";
    recordRef.type = 'salesOrder';

    console.log('Getting Sales Order record');
    return service.get(recordRef);
  })
  .then(function(result, raw, soapHeader) {
    if (result.readResponse.status.$attributes.isSuccess !== 'true') {
      console.error('Error');
      console.error(result.readResponse.status.statusDetail);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    console.log('Last Request:');
    console.log(service.config.client.lastRequest);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error('Last Request:');
    console.error(service.config.client.lastRequest);
  });
```

Above is the code I am executing to get salesOrder;

Answer (score 1):

Believe the Record Type you want is `SalesOrder`, not `salesOrder`.

Reference: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/schema/record/salesorder.html